# How can I get value when click option in the select on vue?

Tags: select, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <small class="text-muted">Quality</small><br>
        <b-form-select class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
                       :options="optQuality"
                       v-model="slcQuality" @change="changeQuality">
        </b-form-select>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data () {
            return {
                optQuality: [
                    { value: 1, text: 'Original' },
                    { value: 2, text: 'Kw-1' },
                    { value: 3, text: 'Kw-2' }
                ],
                slcQuality: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeQuality() {
                console.log('test')
                console.log(this.slcQuality)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I select option Kw-1, I get result of the value is 1

If I select again option Kw-2, I get result of the value is 2

The result is incorrect

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `change`-event occurs **before** `slcQuality` is updated via `v-model` (which occurs with the `input`-event). `changeQuality` is logging the value of `slcQuality` at that time, so it may appear as though `slcQuality` isn't being updated, but it actually occurs in a subsequent event.

You can see an updated value by listening for `input` instead of `change`:

```
<b-form-select @input="changeQuality">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2kwmv70pz)

Comment: @Success No problem :)